# "Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router

In the dashboard page (logged in) when I delete the session storage is shows this error and my browser got hang suddenly and shows this error "See https://crbug.com/1038223. Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protectionpush @ history.ts:646"

Or is just the deletion of session storage that causes the glitch.

here's the code

//app.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard";
import Signin from "./components/signin";
import Signup from "./components/signup";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";
import Footer from "./components/footer";
import Home from "./components/home";
import PageNotFound from "./components/pagenotfound";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        <Route path="/signin" element={<Signin />} />
        <Route
          path="/dashboard"
          element={
            <PrivateRoute>
              <Dashboard />
            </PrivateRoute>
          }
        />
        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//privateRoute

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "./config/firebase";

function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Observe user auth changes
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user ) => {
      if (user) {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
      } else {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    // Unsubscribe when component is unmounted
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>; // Optional loading indicator

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/signin" replace />;
  }

  return children;
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

//signup.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "../config/firebase";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import bgimage from "../assets/bg-image.jpg";

function Signup() {
  const location = useLocation();

  const preFilledEmail = location.state?.email || "";

  const [email, setEmail] = useState(preFilledEmail);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleNavigate = () => {
    navigate("/signin");
  };

  console.log(auth?.currentUser?.email);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userFromStorage = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user"));
    if (userFromStorage && !auth.currentUser) {
      console.log(userFromStorage);
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [navigate]);

  const signUp = async () => {
    try {
      if (isValidEmail(email) && isValidPassword(password)) {
        await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(auth.currentUser));
        navigate("/dashboard");
      } else if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
        alert("Please enter a Valid email");
      } else if (!isValidPassword(password)) {
        alert("Please must contain 6 letters.");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const isValidEmail = (email) => {
    const emailRegex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i;
    return emailRegex.test(email);
  };
  const isValidPassword = async (password) => {
    return password.length >= 6;
  };

  return (
    <div className="body">
      <div className="image-container">
        <img alt="" src={bgimage} />
        <div className="overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="form-input-box">
        <div className="form-input">
          <h1>Sign Up</h1>
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button onClick={signUp}>Sign up</button>
          <p id="text-1">Need help?</p>
          <p id="text-2">
            Have an Account? &nbsp;
            <span
              onClick={handleNavigate}
              style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "white" }}
            >
              Sign in now
            </span>
          </p>
          <p id="text-3">
            This page is protected by Google reCAPTCHA to ensure you're not a
            bot.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Signup;
```